# running js locally keep getting this error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run `discord.js` locally, but I keep getting this error:

[image: error]

This is on **line 6**:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

And here is my **full code**:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = '***';
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!');
});
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping'){
        message.channel.sendMessage('pong');
    }
});
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: What is the error? No screenshot in the link.

Comment: What is the link you are providing here?

Comment: @Franco http://prntscr.com/cr5qt7

Comment: @Matz http://prntscr.com/cr5qt7

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function comes with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org).

If you are double-clicking the file, you are just letting windows do the executing, make sure to execute the file using your command line (`cmd`) and the corresponding command.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. Im trying to run a bot, not open the application discord.

Answer (score 0):

require();

Is a commonjs specification for module loading, it's not built into browsers.
NodeJs has commonjs built in.  For browsers you have to use a packaging system, like browserfy or webpack etc.

Another note, browser in the future will be getting module loading, but will neither be commonjs or AMD, but it will be similar to commonjs.